# The ajax result is not returned

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, model-view-controller, mybatis

I'm trying to import MySQL data(select query) using spring, mybatis.
In js, call the controller function via ajax, and get DB data from the controller.

ex. 
ajax 
url: /testmysql
controller 
requestmapping: /testmysql 
return mav (modelandview)

sysout(mav) is good for the controller.
But Ajax is not found(404) in js.

I was told that an ajax 404 error comes out when there is no return value.
But what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You are making ajax call without root context url of your application.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/context/testmysql',
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
 });
```